Sentinel 2 cloud and shadow mask with s2ClearSky and CLOUD_PROBABILITY in GEE
I'm trying to combine two masking processes, one which works good for clouds in my region, and another one which works well for cloud shadows, however, the resulting image is clipped to the mask, as shown in the image; below is the code I'm working on:

var region = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* shown: false */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-95.99101909722883, 18.873430940932074],
          [-95.99101909722883, 18.517003648320692],
          [-95.57353862847883, 18.517003648320692],
          [-95.57353862847883, 18.873430940932074]]], null, false);


Map.setOptions("SATELLITE")
function s2ClearSky(image) {
      var scl = image.select('SCL');
      var clear_sky_pixels = scl.eq(3).or(scl.eq(6));
      return image.updateMask(clear_sky_pixels).divide(10000);
}

var s2Sr = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED');
var s2Clouds = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY');

var START_DATE = ee.Date('2018-12-01');
var END_DATE = START_DATE.advance(20, 'days');
var MAX_CLOUD_PROBABILITY = 30;

Map.centerObject(region, 13);

function maskClouds(img) {
  var clouds = ee.Image(img.get('cloud_mask')).select('probability');
  var isNotCloud = clouds.lt(MAX_CLOUD_PROBABILITY);
  return img.updateMask(isNotCloud);
}

function maskEdges(s2_img) {
  return s2_img.updateMask(
      s2_img.select('B8A').mask().updateMask(s2_img.select('B9').mask()));
}


var criteria = ee.Filter.and(
    ee.Filter.bounds(region), ee.Filter.date(START_DATE, END_DATE));
s2Sr = s2Sr.filter(criteria).map(maskEdges);
s2Clouds = s2Clouds.filter(criteria);

// Join S2 SR with cloud probability dataset to add cloud mask.
var s2SrWithCloudMask = ee.Join.saveFirst('cloud_mask').apply({
  primary: s2Sr,
  secondary: s2Clouds,
  condition:
      ee.Filter.equals({leftField: 'system:index', rightField: 'system:index'})
});

var s2CloudMasked =
    ee.ImageCollection(s2SrWithCloudMask)
          .map(maskClouds)
          .mean();
var rgbVis = {min: 0, max: 3000, bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2']};

var s2sinsombras = s2ClearSky(s2CloudMasked);

Map.addLayer(
    s2sinsombras, rgbVis, 'S2 SR masked at ' + MAX_CLOUD_PROBABILITY + '%',
    true);


It seems like the masking based on SCL is causing you issues. If your goal is to do both cloud and cloud shadow masking, Cloud Score+ could be an option.
var CLEAR_THRESHOLD = 0.6
var QA_BAND = 'cs' // or cs_cdf

function maskClouds(img) {
  return img.updateMask(img.select(QA_BAND).gte(CLEAR_THRESHOLD));
}

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
  .filterBounds(region)
  .filterDate(START_DATE, END_DATE)
  .linkCollection('GOOGLE/CLOUD_SCORE_PLUS/V1/S2_HARMONIZED', [QA_BAND])
  .map(maskClouds)
  
var s2CloudMasked = collection.mean()

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d3f716b878b2e8d0fa634826272ab16d
